Delete files from WhatsApp without deleting files in Gallery
I'd like to delete some files on my Android device (Xiaomi) by deleting files stored by WhatsApp that I didn't save in my gallery.
I have a few questions.

If I understand correctly, whenever I send a media by WhatsApp (being it a video recorded in the app or a video/picture already existing in my gallery) it creates a copy of the media in the following folder. Is it correct?
Internal memory\Android\media\com.whatsapp\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Video\Sent
Internal memory\Android\media\com.whatsapp\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Images\Sent

If I delete those media (even if they were originally in my gallery), will I delete them also from the gallery or only from that folder?

I see that in my gallery I have some media from Internal memory\Android\media\com.whatsapp\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Video. These are the media I received by WhatsApp and I saved in my gallery (be default or explicitly). Is it correct? In this case, if I delete them, I would delete them also in my gallery (meaning I won't have them anymore on my device).



In general, gallery apps do not save the media file. They scan the internal storage for existing media files and show them in the app. Anything happened to the media files in the internal storage will directly affect the media in the gallery app.

Yes, WhatsApp will create a copy of the media in the Sent folders when the user sends a media file to someone.

Deleting the media files in the Sent folders will not affect the original media files shown in the gallery. However, if the gallery app is also told to scan the Sent folder, then there will be duplicate media in the gallery app; one for the original, and another from the Sent folder (check the media location from the gallery app to be sure).

Yes, received media will be stored in WhatsApp Images or WhatsApp Video folders. If the files are deleted from these folders, then (in general case*) the gallery app will not be able to find and show the media anymore.



*Worth noting that some gallery apps may support automatic cloud sync/backup. If the media is already backed up to the cloud, then the gallery app may still show the media (from the cloud) even though the original file has already been deleted from the internal storage.
